# Chrome toLocaleTimeString()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website which should display the local time of the browser i use.

I save the locale Time in a konckout observable

```
self.startTimeText(time.toLocaleTimeString("HH:MM:ss"));
```

Using this in Opera, Safari, or Firefox it causes no problems, only in Chorme it doesn't work. 
Nothing is displayd and the programm seems to stop working

Answer (score 0):

time.toUTCString() may work better with chrome. i haven't tested it. but you could give it a shot.